# How can I link an existing Git to my current environment without downloading all the files?

Tags: git, github

I would like to link my current git repo to an updated version of the repo on my computer that wasn't being tracked.

However, if I clone it... it will download the old repo on top of it.

Is there a way where I can clone without downloading the files, then scan for real differences between the folder and the repo, and push those changes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+into+non-empty+directory

Comment: Thanks @phd this did it!

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the old Github repo as an origin to your new repo with:

```
git remote add origin <repo-url>
```

Then you can do:

```
git fetch origin
```

And to compare your current changes (assuming they're in master branch) to the Github repo's files:

```
git diff master origin/master
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a remote to a branch. It is described in detail [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) under "Adding Remote Repositories":

```
git remote add my_new_remote https://github.com/paulboone/ticgit
```